# Syntax for defining and calling custom javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I call a custom defined function from within a jQuery click event?

I define a `clearOrder` function that executes some actions.
Then, when I click on a DOM element, I want to call that function, and then do some more actions.

The actions are simply applying and removing classes. As you can see I want to clear the specified existing classes from elements as a sort of reset before adding specific classes to the DOM elements.

html

```
<div id="neti" class="tile"> contents </div>
<div id="sife" class="tile"> contents </div>
```

javascript

```
(function() {
  clearOrder(function() {
    return $('.tile').removeClass("order-1 order-2 order-3 order-4 order-5 order-6 order-7 order-8 order-9 order-10 order-11 order-12 order-13 order-14 order-15 order-16");
  });

  jQuery(function() {
    $('#neti').click(function() {
      clearOrder.call;
      $('this').addClass("active");
      $('#neti').addClass("order-1");
      $('#sife').addClass("order-2");

    });
  });

}).call(this);
```

The script behavior should be that when I click on an element, it should remove all of the specified classes, then apply certain classes.

---

edit: changed to the following, but still not functioning.

```
(function() {
  clearOrder(function() {
    return $('.tile').removeClass("order-1 order-2 order-3 order-4 order-5 order-6 order-7 order-8 order-9 order-10 order-11 order-12 order-13 order-14 order-15 order-16");
  });

  jQuery(function() {
    $('#neti').click(function() {
      clearOrder();
      $('this').addClass("active");
      $('#neti').addClass("order-1");
      $('#sife').addClass("order-2");
```

Comment: just add `()` at the end of the function name to invoke it.. like `clearOrder();`... there is no need to use `.call`

Comment: I tried your suggestion. It does not seem to function properly still.

Comment: any error in your browser console

Comment: no, it loads, but just doesn't behave properly: there is no visible adding or removing of any classes in the inspector.

Comment: Currently you're not defining `clearOrder`. Can you display where it's defined? (I'm thinking maybe it's scoped so your anonymous function can't get to it, which would cause it to error out).

Comment: oh, i thought i was defining it where it is right now, and calling it from wtihin the jQuery portion.

from coffeescript, i have `clearOrder -> .....` and `jQuery ->.....` but they both automatically get wrapped in a function, and called at the end. In other words, I can't seem to take them outside of their current scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple problems

```
(function () {
    //function declaration syntax was wrong
    function clearOrder() {
        return $('.tile').removeClass("order-1 order-2 order-3 order-4 order-5 order-6 order-7 order-8 order-9 order-10 order-11 order-12 order-13 order-14 order-15 order-16");
    };

    jQuery(function ($) {
        $('#neti').click(function () {
            //add () to the end of the function reference to invoke it
            clearOrder();
            // this is not a string literal, it has to be used as a keyword(without enclosing '') to refer the current clicked element
            $(this).addClass("active");
            $('#neti').addClass("order-1");
            $('#sife').addClass("order-2");

        });
    });

}).call(this);
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/UC56H/)

Comment: where/why does the $ in `jQuery(function ($) {` come from?

Comment: jQuery passes an instance of self to the dom ready handler method, so that we can refer to the jQuery using any variable name that we like...

Comment: thank you so much!!!

Using this tool, I was able to figure out the coffee as well.

http://haml-html-coffeecup-javascript-coffeescript-converter.smullindesign.com/